# Optimal query for comparing table column vs. summary column

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

What is the most efficient way to stack a field on one table with a summary field summarizing child data in another table?

For example, I have an `account` table and a `task` table. Below is the query I'm currently executing to compare a stamped value on the `account` table to actual counts from the `task` table.

```
SELECT
    account.sfid,
    account.lastactivitydate,
    account.sales_activities_last_30_days__c AS expectedcount,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM salesforce.task
        WHERE task.accountid = account.sfid AND
              task.activitydate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '60 days'
    ) AS actualcount
FROM salesforce.account
;
```

This is a naive attempt to get the data I want, and I'd appreciate any suggestions on optimizing this query to get results like what's shown in the table below.

```
sfid lastactivitydate expectedcount actualcount
---- ---------------- ------------- -----------
abc  2019-11-30       3             3
def  2019-11-27       5             4
```

Comment: Your query looks fine, except the mismatch between 30 and 60.  If you want performance advice, please show an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query, and see https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 0):

Test

```sql
SELECT account.sfid,
       account.lastactivitydate,
       account.sales_activities_last_30_days__c AS expectedcount,
       COALESCE(subquery.cnt, 0) AS actualcount
FROM salesforce.account
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT task.accountid, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM salesforce.task
            WHERE task.activitydate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '60 days'
            GROUP BY task.accountid
          ) AS subquery ON subquery.accountid = account.sfid;
```

or

```sql
SELECT account.sfid,
       account.lastactivitydate,
       account.sales_activities_last_30_days__c AS expectedcount,
       COUNT(task.accountid) AS actualcount
FROM salesforce.account
LEFT JOIN salesforce.task 
    ON task.accountid = account.sfid
   AND task.activitydate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '60 days'
GROUP BY account.sfid,
         account.lastactivitydate,
         account.sales_activities_last_30_days__c;
```